# sqlalchemy query: result column names

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a model (declared using Declarative base) called `DevicesGpsTelemetry`. I make query like this:

```
models = session.query(
    DevicesGps.ReceivedDateUtc, 
    DevicesGps.ReceivedTimeUtc,   
    DevicesGps.Latitude,                                 
    DevicesGps.Longitude)
```

And it renders as:

```
    SELECT   
    devices_gps."ReceivedDateUtc" AS "devices_gps_ReceivedDateUtc", 
    devices_gps."ReceivedTimeUtc" AS "devices_gps_ReceivedTimeUtc", 
    devices_gps."Latitude" AS "devices_gps_Latitude", 
    devices_gps."Longitude" AS "devices_gps_Longitude" 
        FROM devices_gps
```

My question: how to change the names which go after AS statement (like `"gps_telemetry_ReceivedDateUtc"`) to something I want?

Background: these names are important for me because I do `pandas.read_sql` with this query and the names become DataFrame's column names

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `.label('desired_name')` after each column. In your case it would look like

```
models = session.query(
    DevicesGps.ReceivedDateUtc.label("gps_telemetry_ReceivedDateUtc"), 
    DevicesGps.ReceivedTimeUtc.label("gps_telemetry_ReceivedTimeUtc"),   
    DevicesGps.Latitude.label("gps_telemetry_Latitude"),                                 
    DevicesGps.Longitude.label("gps_telemetry_Longitude")
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Somehow missed this in documentation